# Could not access windows environment variable in Node

Tags: node.js, windows

Today I was trying to write an environment variable like this:

```
set PORT=5000
```

But when I access it through the process.env.PORT variable in node, it gives undefined.

I might be missing something or my PC is malfunctioning, so any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Setting environment variables doesn't retroactively change the environment of already running processes.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it more lightly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below command to set the port number in node process while running node JS program. And this port will only limited to this node process.

```
set PORT =3000 && node file_name.js
```

The set port can be accessed in the code as

```
process.env.PORT
```

I recommend you using .environment file to keep your configuration separate.

Steps to follow:

- create a package.json file
- install the dotenv npm package
- write the code to read the .env
- run the code

.env

```
# .env.example
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=8626
# Set your database connection information here 
API_KEY=your-core-api-key-goes-here
```

server.js file:

```
// server.js
console.log(`Your port is ${process.env.PORT}`); // undefined
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
console.log(`Your port is ${process.env.PORT}`); // 8626
```

for more details you can check this: https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js-html

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried with dotenv and it worked!! I was adding authentication to my app, but when I had to access the private key for jwt in the environment variable it gave me undefined and I got frustrated, but it works now, thank you!

Comment: Right, but when I host my app won't this file be available to anyone who can access my codebase? Can't they just read the secrets in the .env file?

Comment: Environment variables exist outside our application's code, they are available where our application is running. For that to work you can go this article : https://stackabuse.com/managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-with-dotenv/

Comment: Got it, so when I host I host my app to Heroku, etc. they'd allow me to set the environment variable there itself, so I don't need to configure the .env file. Right?

Comment: No, you don't need to add .env file to heroku env instead heroku gives they provided their own env setting to make it work. Remember never add this file as a part of your source code.  check this out : https://dev.to/numtostr/comment/k026